# How to remove single view from Prism Navigation Journal

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm using Prism navigation (version 6.3.0) on a WPF application,

I've 3 views: ***ViewA*** , ***ViewB*** and ***ViewC***, 
after navigating from ViewA to ViewC passing by ViewB I want to remove ViewB from Navigation Journal, to call the GoBack method and navigate directly to ViewA

#### First Navigation

ViewA -> <s>ViewB</s>  -> **ViewC**

#### Second Navigation (GoBack)

ViewC -> **ViewA**

I tried implementing the method `OnNavigatedFrom` in the following way but it doesn't work:

```
public override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    this.NavigationJournal.Clear();
    var viewAEntry = new RegionNavigationJournalEntry() { Uri = new Uri(ContractNames.Medics, UriKind.Relative) };
    this.NavigationJournal.RecordNavigation(viewAEntry);
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(navigationContext);
}
```

I've also checked the reported issues on Github ( [30](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/30) and [384](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/384) ) 
but seems are without a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't built into the framework just yet, but if you follow the directions in this comment you should be able to implement a solution.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/30#issuecomment-227491454

and

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/30#issuecomment-227679365

That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @Brian , I tried to apply the suggested solution, if we change the constructor parameter of **MyRegionNavigationService** to IMyRegionNavigationJournal means change all the properties of this class having or using type IRegionNavigationJournal to IMyRegionNavigationJournal which mismatch with the implementation of IRegionNavigationService that has all properties with IRegionNavigationJournal. I don't know if i create a custom **IMyRegionNavigationService** interface using IMyRegionNavigationJournal will solve the problem ? or will affect other usages in the unmodified Prism classes ?

Comment: You don't change any ctor definitions. You simply register your concrete classes with the Prism interfaces with the container. `Container.RegisterType<IRegionNavigationJournal, MyNavJournal>(make singleton)`